# How to capture the authentication events?

Tags: spring-security

I tried the following:

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">

    <property name="providers">
        <list>
          <ref local="myAuthnProvider"/>
        </list>
      </property>

    <property name="authenticationEventPublisher">
        <bean class="myPublisher/>
    </property>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationManager" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

But I get an exception during startup. I also tried with the constructor tag, same result:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: secify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:250)
```

I'm using spring 3.1.1.

Any ideas why this error is thrown? Or other suggestions on how to capture the authentication events? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you want to do is get notified about authentication events, then you don't have to customize the `AuthenticationManager`. It's enough to implement the `ApplicationListener` interface as shown below, and put a bean of this type in the same spring context where security is configured.

```
public class AuthenticationEventListener 
        implements ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationEvent event) {
        // process the event
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the basic Java interfaces involved. You are creating a bean of type `Providermanager` (interface `AuthenticationManager`) and you are attempting to assign it to something which should be of type `AuthenticationProvider`, hence you get an error.

The `authentication-manager` namespace element creates a `ProviderManager` instance itself, so you would then have two instances in the same configuration.

In the latest versions of Spring Security, you can inject a custom `AuthenticationManager` into the web configuration using:

```
<http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
   ...
```

and bypass using the namespace for the `AuthenticationManager` completely.